# Failing to compile blender 2.80 - help needed

Tags: python

I am trying to compile blender 2.80 so that I can later compile the sphinx docs for the updated python API.
My ultimate goal, is accessing the new API docs.
But it would be great to understand why I keep failing to compile blender.

I made a docker image specifically for compiling blender, I followed the official build instructions, and I do install all the dependencies.
This is my work so far, it can take about ~2-3 hours to install all the dependencies and compile.
https://github.com/egidijus/blender-compile

The error I receive while compiling is:

```
-- Found OpenImageIO: /opt/lib/oiio/lib/libOpenImageIO.so  
-- Found OpenColorIO: /opt/lib/ocio/lib/static/libOpenColorIO.a;/opt/lib/ocio/lib/libyaml-cpp.a;/opt/lib/ocio/lib/libtinyxml.a  
-- Could NOT find LLVM (missing: LLVM_LIBRARY) 
-- LLVM not found
-- Found OpenSubdiv: /opt/lib/osd/lib/libosdGPU.so;/opt/lib/osd/lib/libosdCPU.so  
-- Found OpenMP_C: -fopenmp (found version "4.5") 
-- Found OpenMP_CXX: -fopenmp (found version "4.5") 
-- Found OpenMP: TRUE (found version "4.5")  
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:909 (message):
  Cycles OSL requires WITH_LLVM, the library may not have been found.
  Configure LLVM or disable WITH_CYCLES_OSL


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "//build_linux_full/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "//build_linux_full/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [all] Error 1
GNUmakefile:268: recipe for target 'all' failed
ERROR: Service 'blender' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c make full' returned a non-zero code: 2
make: *** [Makefile:11: build] Error 1
```

I would appreciate any help! 
Thanks!

Comment: for questions regarding building Blender, it's better to ask that at the devtalk forum. There is a solution provided to the LLVM issue you mention provided here: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/i-had-to-reinstall-ubuntu-again-and-i-cant-get-my-blender-2-8-to-build-properly-again/3969/3

Comment: Thanks aliasguru, let me try and update the question.

Comment: Questions about developing Blender in  C/C++/C# are off topic on Blender Stack Exchange, I believe that would include building Blender. Devtalk forums is a lot better place for this, you are more likely to get better help there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about building Blender and building is part of developing Blender in C/C++/C# which is off topic on Blender Stack Exchange. (See: [What questions should be definitely off-topic?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic) )

Comment: Further to link posted by @aliasguru I find `cmake-gui` a handy tool for configuring blenders cmake. Put in advanced mode shows all the settings. Has folder / file select box to manually set those not found by configure.

Comment: I managed to compile, but I am unhappy with the outcome, because I have not included all the appropriate CMAKE instructions, and so it explodes when I try to compile python docs....

I will carry on trying to make a predictable blender builder.